# How to get the number of post a user has in instagram?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, bots

I am creating a instagram bot using selenium python. I just wanted to know how to retrieve the number of the post a user contain in their profile page. So that I can handle the "NO POSTS YET" condition in my script.

Can anyone give me a hint. I don't need a complete code or just hint me to the right place.

Example profile : https://www.instagram.com/michelemessina/

Comment: Use the Instagram API, instead of scraping the individual profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text of the element via xPath:

```
//span[text() = ' posts']/span
```

[image: img]

Comment: thanks but i'll be go with window._sharedData.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use find_element_by_xpath since xpath can be easily found in chrome.

Here's how: right click -> inspect -> right click -> Copy -> CopyXpath

`xpath = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[1]/span/span' 
if browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text == '0':
    pass`

Answer (score 1):

According to your task I wrote a few lines that get amount of posts, followers and following. You can run the code to view results.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/michelemessina/')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)

posts = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li/span[text()=" posts"]/span'))).text
followers = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li/a[text()=" followers"]/span'))).text
following = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li/a[text()=" following"]/span'))).text
print('Posts: {}; Followers: {}; Following: {}.'.format(posts, followers, following))
```

Hope, this will help you.